# Dual SIM iPhone sends silent SMS although iMessage and Facetime are turned off

Tags: iphone, sms, esim

I am using an iPhone 11 pro with an eSIM and a foreign SIM card. Whenever i activate the latter line, the phone sends [a silent SMS ro the number, apparently to activate iMessage and Facetime](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7348383).

However, this SMS costs me quite some money as I am “abroad”.  Naturally I tried switching off iMessage and Facetime for that number. Unfortunately, the phone keeps sending the silent SMS. Is there way to avoid this?

Update: May this also be related to WiFi-Calling?